# Function with return type of 'string' returns a nullable string (ie 'string?')

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, nullable-reference-types

For an Azure Functions project I am using C# 8 with enabled nullable reference types. Since with AzureFunctions AppSettings are exposed via environment variables, which can be a string or null (i.e. they return `string?`) I tried to encapsulate the logic of getting environment variables - and throwing an error if they're not set - into a separate method `GetEnvVariable`.

As you can see, `GetEnvVariable` is implemented in three short lines. If the environment variable is not set (i.e it is `null`) it *throws* a custom exception, else the string value is *returned*.

The following line does not show a problem of "possible de-reference of null" because the compiler know, that at this line `env` must be `string` (not `string?`) because the exception would have fired already and this line could not have been reached.

> var length = env.Contains('$');

Still, when hovering over the variable `env` with the mouse the type is displayed as `string?`

Does this make sense? If so, why? `env` is assigned the output of the `GetEnvVariable` method, which return `string`.

Does throwing an exception implicitly return `null`? Please help me understand, your input is really appreciated. Cheers!

Here's my code

```cs
namespace delme_azf
{
    public static class kv
    {
        [FunctionName("kv")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                var envName = "lolomat";
                var env = GetEnvVariable(envName);
                var length = env.Contains('$');
                return new OkObjectResult($"success {env}");
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }


        public static string GetEnvVariable(string name)
        {
            var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name);
            if (env == null) throw new EnvironmentVariableNotSetException(nameof(name));
            return env;
        }


        public class EnvironmentVariableNotSetException : Exception
        {
            public EnvironmentVariableNotSetException() {}
            public EnvironmentVariableNotSetException(string envName) : base($"Mandatory environment variable '{envName}' is not set.") {}
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Also here's my full *.csproj showing that nullable reference types are enabled globally.

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>delme_azf</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core" Version="2.19.70" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Btw, a bit off topic but you can make use of IOptions<T> and bind your configuration to strongly typed classes and inject them into your functions. It removes the need for working with environment variables directly and you can add validation if needed. It's almost the same as doing it a full application, exception you need to do it in FunctionStartup

Comment: Hey that sounds really interesting. I already use DI so the startup class is inheriting from from FunctionsStartup. I found this blog entry tahat seems to pick up on that idea 

https://medium.com/@therealjordanlee/dependency-injection-in-azure-functions-v3-7148d0574dfc

Comment: Ya just look at the AddOptions+Configure in his sample. The trick is that you need to set up "sections" in your settings. This simply means adding a prefix to their names. Ie, `MySection__lolomat` so that you can bind (for ex) `IOptions<MySectionOptions>` to only the relevant settings

Comment: I will try that, thanks. Still I'm curious as to why the below is saying the envName and env variables are of type "string?"

Comment: Okay, I got it working with strongly typed settings. AS presented in the link above I even encapsulated this in a separate service to inject somewhere else. But STILL, when `var settingsValue = appSettingsService.lolomat` displays as data type "string?" in VS code when hovering over it with the mouse. So it's the same behaviours as below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throwing an exception does not make your method return null or any other value.

When you declare a `var` of a reference type, the compiler will always infer a nullable type for it. The reason for this is that the compiler has full knowledge of whether or not the variable could contain null at any point in the method--so if you wanted to do something like the following, the compiler can understand what you're doing and stay out of your way:

```
var x = "initial value";
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString()); // ok

if (someCondition)
{
    // there's no warning on this assignment, because
    // `var x` was inferred to have a `string?` type in the beginning.
    x = null;
}

CarryOnWith(x); // ok, assuming the method accepts a possibly null string
```

Visual Studio will show you the null state the compiler has inferred for your variable in Quick Info (by hovering over the variable):

[image: Quick Info example 1]

[image: Quick Info example 2]

See also the [notes](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-12-18.md#var) from the C# design team on the decision to make `var` always infer a nullable reference type.

---

Below is some more context on what the language is doing:

Nullability analysis tracks both the *declared type* of a variable and the *flow state* of a variable. Consider an example like the following:

```cs
string? s = null;
if (s != null)
{
    // if we somehow got here, s was not null.
    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
}
else
{
    // warning: dereference of a possibly null reference
    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
}

s = "hello";
// since we know a not-null was assigned, we now know this is safe.
Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());

// additionally the flow state becomes not-null if
// a null value would have definitely caused an exception earlier on:
s = null;
// warning
Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
// no warning, because the previous line would have already thrown an exception
Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
```

In the above example, `s` is of type `string?`, but the compiler knows at each point whether or not it could contain `null`-- so it's OK to access members on it or pass it off to methods that require a `string` argument.

Comment: Thank you. I think I get it know. My error I'm thinking was that I didn't realise that I `could` reassign my variable to a null, and that's why the type was shown as `string?`. But does this mean, that when using nullable reference types using the `var` keyword is not encouraged anymore? Every variable I declare with implicit typing will have a `?` at the end of the type name

Comment: It is definitely encouraged to use `var` with nullable reference types :)

Comment: @baouss Don't forget the compiler's analysis will still know the actual value assigned is not-null - only if there's a path that actually potentially allows null to be assigned do you have to add a null check later on. `string?` doesn't mean the local is _definitely_ null - it just allows it to be assigned null at some point.

Answer (score 0):

> the compiler know, that at this line `env` must be `string` (not `string?`) because the exception would have fired already and this line could not have been reached.

No, it doesn't. The compiler does not do in-depth analysis to know that your function *cannot* return a `null` value.

If you've enabled nullable reference support either within the `.csproj` file or via a `#nullable enable` directive, then using the `string` return type (as opposed to `string?`) for `GetEnvVariable` informs the compiler that the reference cannot be set be null. Without that support turned on, the compiler assumes that the string van be null.

Comment: Thanks. But I thought that was the whole point of nullable reference types. How do you explain then, that when getting the env directly via Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("lolomat") - ie not via my helper method - I get the following compiler warning "Warning CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference."

Comment: If you've turned on nullable support in the project file or through a directive, then setting the return type to `string` should work - I'm assuming based on the intellisense that nullable support is _not_ turned on.

Comment: Nullable support is enabled in my csproj.

Comment: @baouss Then it may be a bug in the intellisense or in the pre-compiler that is not honoring that directive. Do you get a compiler error if you try to set `env=null`?

Comment: @D Stanley and @JamesFaix, I edited the question to include the csproj file

Comment: Hell, I just realised that even the variable "envName" is of type "string?". How can this be?