# Incorrect warning Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type

Tags: c#

I try:

```
var err = (string)null;
```

(which I prefer to `string? err=null;`)

I get

> warning CS8600: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

But the type of `err` is correctly set to a nullable string as is evident by hovering over it in visual studio.

Is this warning a dud ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have nullable reference types turned on, the warning is correctly pointing out that you are casting `null` to a non-nullable type - `string`. It is not about the type of `err` being non-nullable. `err` *is* nullable, [as `var`s always are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62685673/in-c-sharp-8-why-does-type-inference-on-new-expressions-result-in-nullable-refe).

If you cast to `string?` instead, which *is* nullable, then the warning goes away:

```
var err = (string?)null;
```