# Why does ToList() return a Nullable List<T> instead of a List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, nullable-reference-types

While implementing the Nullablility feature in my code, I found out, that `ToList()` returns a `List<T>?` instead of a `List<T>` when the result is declared as `var` and I was unable to figure out, why that is the case.

Both of these compile without warnings. However the latter is `List<int>?` instead of `List<int>`:

```
List<int> collection1 = Array.Empty<int>().ToList();
var collection2 = Array.Empty<int>().ToList();
```

Looking at the [System.Linq.csproj](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e9036b04357e8454439a0e6cf22186a0cb19e616/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System.Linq.csproj#L4) file on github, I found out that it has

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Then looking at the [ToList() implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e9036b04357e8454439a0e6cf22186a0cb19e616/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/ToCollection.cs#L22), I saw that is has the following implementation

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.source);
    }

    return source is IIListProvider<TSource> listProvider ? listProvider.ToList() : new List<TSource>(source);
}
```

Because `new List<TSource>(source)` is never `null`, I looked at [IIListProvider](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/release/6.0/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/IIListProvider.cs) and found the following declaration:

```
List<TElement> ToList();
```

So this does not return `List<T>?` either.

My question is:
**Why does the compiler still think, that the `ToList()` method can return a `List<T>?` while no code paths can return a nullable value?**

Comment: "`ToList()` returns a `List<T>?`" No it doesn't. Can you show a [mcve] showing that it does? Are we thinking about different `ToList()`s?

Comment: I just added an example. It only happens if the result is declared as `var`.

Comment: Can you please share code reproducing the issue? I don't get any warnings [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEB0AZAlgOwI4G5YFkIAWQmWAYmwFcAbegQwCN6BTRd7VjogZmRhEAYUQBvWImnJBIUogCyAHgAqAPgAUKfmvWIAzgHtaAJwDG7AJQSpM+3fvSAbk1OIAHogC8hkxfZUVSMsAwAXTSsKJxkUAE5ND1QRE2wwqMcnTIBfWGygA===). And  `ToList()` does not return a `List<T>?` (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-6.0))

Comment: And check the inferred type of that `var` declare variable.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/62685673/15498

Comment: That's nothing to do with `ToList`. It's because you are using `var`.

Comment: @wertzui this is how `var` type inference works. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var).

Comment: Thanks Damien_The_Unbeliever and guru-stron. These links provide the answers, I was looking for.